# What is the aborted flag of fetch's response?

Tags: javascript, http, fetch

When I use `location.href='https://google.com'`, the fetch request has already been sent, but is aborted by webview or browser as js does the location.href jump.

How can we get the abort flag? in the fetch standard doc concept-response-aborted

> [A response can have an associated aborted flag, which is initially unset.](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#responses)
> This indicates that the request was intentionally aborted by the developer or end-user.

what is the aborted flag? How can developer get this flag? or chrome fetch listed, use error.name === 'AbortError'?

```
fetch(url, { signal }).then(response => {
  return response.text();
}).then(text => {
  console.log(text);
}).catch(err => {
  if (err.name === 'AbortError') {
    console.log('Fetch aborted');
  } else {
    console.error('Uh oh, an error!', err);
  }
});
```

Comment: can you provide a link to the quoted sentence ?

Comment: The `aborted flag` is a spec concept that is internal to the algorithm and isn't accessible to user-land scripts.

Comment: _"as js does the location.href jump"_ - navigating to a different page "cancels" any running JS code on the current page anyway, so even if there were a way to get this flag, I doubt you could make any use of it in this situation.